# Website behind Firewall: How to SSL through a Reverse SSH Tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a website (Apache) hosted on my RasPi behind the apartment's firewall. A reverse SSH tunnel is established between the RasPi and a cloud server outside for port forwarding. The site's domain name is pointed to the cloud server's IP address.

**Goal:** Enable SSL connection from outside, via the SSH tunnel, to the site hosted on my RasPi. When someone outside opens the domain name, let them see the green padlock.

[image]

Is this configuration possible? Where should I install the SSL certificate?

Comment: I wrote a article on Medium that you might find helpful for this titled "How To Use A Digital Ocean VPS And Caddy As A Reverse Proxy For A Self Hosted Raspberry Pi Website (Behind A Firewall) Using An SSH Reverse Tunnel" Check it out at https://rickjacobo.medium.com/how-to-use-a-digital-ocean-vps-and-caddy-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-a-self-hosted-raspberry-pi-website-d4377008397c